# How do I architect Microsoft Project Server 2007 in a geographically distributed environment?

Tags: project-server

We're experiencing major performance issues when users try to save and publish large project plans remotely from Microsoft Project Professional 2007.

What would be the best way to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess Project assumes it is on a local network and the performance is killed by the large delays over the WAN. A hardware solution could be a [steelhead](http://www.riverbed.com)

And if those are software projects, switching to a more sensible project planning tool would improve performance the most :)